# SQLAchemy ORM MetaData when used with multiple engines keeps first representation of engine

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy orm and have multiple users being able to query my api. I keep all user engines stored separately and accessible only via JWT verification. I use their engine when booting up the api to form a dictionary of the following format:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "table1": {
      "column1": table1.c.column1
    }
  }
}
```

and repeat this for every user in my database who I want to access the api. Code is as follows:

```
def build_translation_per_db(connections):
    metadata=MetaData()
    database_engines = {}
    translation_per_db = {}
    for connection in connections:
        db_tag = connection['db_tag']
        client = aws_connect_function()
        secret =  function_get_secret()
        
        if type(secret) == list:
            for db in secret['aliases']:
                db_engine_object, db_connection_object=function_return_engine(secret=db, db_tag=db_tag)
                database_engines[db] = {
                    'engine': db_engine_object
                }
        else: 
            db_engine_object, db_connection_object=function_return_engine(secret=secret, db_tag=db_tag)
            database_engines[connection['name']] = {
                'engine': db_engine_object
            }
    # at this point we should have all engines and connections
    for database in database_engines.keys():
        # name of the database 
        table_translation, column_translation_from_table = build_table_translation(database_engines[database]['engine'], metadata)

        translation_per_db[database] = {
            'table_translation': table_translation,
            'column_translation_from_table': column_translation_from_table,
            'engine': database_engines[database]['engine']
        }

    return translation_per_db

def build_table_translation(db_engine_object, metadata):
    table_translation = {}
    tables = db_engine_object.table_names()
    # print(tables)
    for table in tables:
        table_translation[table] = Table(table, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine_object)

    column_translation_from_table = {}
    for table in table_translation.keys():
        column_translation_from_table[table] = {}
        for col in table_translation[table].c:
            column_translation_from_table[table][col.name] = col
```

where the metadata is built before all engines have been acquired. This was resulting in an error where all engine Tables were following the first engine's schema (ie a column present in user2 table2 would not be snagged if user1 table2 did not have that column).

This problem was solved by building the metadata directly in the function build_table_translation rather than passing it in. While this it is good that the bug is resolved, I don't understand why the bug was present in the first place - clearly I missed something from sqlachemy's docs on MetaData. Would appreciate an explanation!

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the original "buggy" function?  It's not clear how you were using the metadata originally.

Comment: It sounds like you were using `metadata` as a global instance of `MetaData()` and calling `build_table_translation` for the first user was polluting it. If different users can have different table definitions (which is a bit troubling, BTW) then they will need to have different `MetaData()` objects.

Comment: @GordThompson Just so I understand better, which user will the metadata act on as it is placed in my above code?
As for the point that it is an issue, agreed, it was temporary and lead me to see this issue before we rolled out a feature to our clients we were testing it and it wasn't coming through when it was not run on all test databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment to the question:

> which user will the metadata act on as it is placed in my above code?

Since `build_translation_per_db()` does `metadata = MetaData()` and then passes that object to each invocation of `build_table_translation()`, all tables will share the same MetaData instance and that instance will contain table information for all users/engines:

```py
from pprint import pprint

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, MetaData, Table


def build_translation_per_db(connections):
    # for demonstration purposes, connections is just a list of strings
    metadata = MetaData()
    return [build_table_translation(conn, metadata) for conn in connections]


def build_table_translation(db_engine_object, metadata):
    # for demonstration purposes, db_engine_object is just a string
    return Table(
        f"{db_engine_object}_table",
        metadata,
        Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    )


conns = ["engine_1", "engine_2"]
table_1, table_2 = build_translation_per_db(conns)

# Do the tables share the same metadata object?
print(table_1.metadata == table_2.metadata)  # True

# What does it contain?
pprint(table_1.metadata.tables)
"""
{'engine_1_table': Table('engine_1_table', MetaData(), Column('id', Integer(), table=<engine_1_table>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), schema=None),
 'engine_2_table': Table('engine_2_table', MetaData(), Column('id', Integer(), table=<engine_2_table>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), schema=None)}
"""
```

If different users can have tables with the same name but different columns then those tables may represent the first user processed, or maybe the last user processed, or perhaps some crazy mish-mash of attributes, but in any case it's not something you want.

Comment: Gotcha, a shared metadata will not reflect any discrepancies in user datamodels. Thank you!